# gCloud with internal load balancing and Windows

Tags: windows, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

I am trying to setup internal load balancing on Google Cloud for windows backend servers but, when I add internal LB to instance group, all windows servers in that instance group get one additional IP (IP of internal LB). When then server tries to access to public sites, access fails if the server uses the IP from LB to access.

Only workaround I currently see is to create public load balancer and limit access to it but there has to be a better way.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you try to specify the IP address for the internal load balancer forwarding rule manually e.g 10.240.0.200 and see if that resolves your issue?

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue with internal load balancer? Did Faizan suggestion helped you? If the issue got solved, consider posting self answer which will help other users looking at this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I solved issue by setting SkipAsSource on all load balancers IP address by running PS script on Win startup...

```
$IPList = (Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object {$_.PrefixOrigin -match "Manual"}).IPAddress

foreach ($IP in $IPList) {
    Set-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $IP -SkipAsSource $true
}
```